# Set volume and lock phone programmatically in windows phone 8 GDR3

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I know there is new APIs in windows phone 8 update3 which enable us to Lock Phone Screen or Set Volume to specific value programmatically. but I can't find sample c# codes.
Can anyone show me sample codes to do this.

---

there are some new apps on windows phone store which have this feature and user can pin "Lock Phone" or "Silent" tile to start screen > like "Quick Tiles: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quick-tiles/1725cca2-2349-4d33-b5d5-8b04e7810c04"

thanks

Comment: I mentioned this in an almost identical question last week. The libraries are in the MSDN documentation. They are in C++ though. If you want to access the volume controls in c# you need to create a reference to a C++ project that does it.

Comment: Just so you don't have to go search it down, this is the link I posted in the other question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681688(v=vs.105).aspx As you can clearly see there is a library and it IS for windows phone.

Comment: Volume api are not official, your app will be delete.