# Changing Rotation Lock Setting Programmatically in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, autorotate, screen-rotation

This is a long shot, but I'm wondering if its possible to enable or disable rotation lock from within an app?

I can't find any documentation on this, but I know since GDR3 there are [**some APIs available**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257175/set-volume-and-lock-phone-programmatically-in-windows-phone-8-gdr3) which allow global settings to be changed

Essentially I want to create an app which will enable or disable auto-rotate depending on the time of day, so at night time it's switched off

Comment: [There are apps which claim to do this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/rotation-lock/1adcd25e-0a2f-4496-b5f9-5a63d0d13214) (without the timing component), so I assume so. They do mention that it requires GDR3.

Comment: I've found two apps in the store that provide a *shortcut* to the rotation lock settings screen, but don't affect it directly... both require GDDR3 so I'm guessing those are the ones you mean? Top two results when searching for "rotation lock"

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. I don't know if you can forcibly set them. You can offer a notification that opens the page though.

Comment: actually that's not a bad idea. Not ideal but better than nothing.